# Unity can play audio channel?

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have an audio, it has four channels, and I want play one of them. Can I do it?

I can't find method in Unity API.

```
public void Play();
public void Play([DefaultValue("0")] ulong delay);
public void PlayDelayed(float delay);
public void PlayOneShot(AudioClip clip);
public void PlayOneShot(AudioClip clip, [DefaultValue("1.0F")] float volumeScale);
public void PlayScheduled(double time);
public void SetScheduledEndTime(double time);
public void SetScheduledStartTime(double time);
public void Stop();
```